# Flash - On Timer Private Function

Tags: flash, function, timer, private

I am trying to get a timer to work for this game. I get an error at line 36: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.

Here is the last part of the hw assignment for you to compare: http://www.lwebdesigns.net/hw1.docx

This is the code I have for my MainTimer
package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;


public class MainTimer extends MovieClip {
    // Init vars for class
    private var currentMin:int;
    private var currentSec:int;
    // create a one second timer from Flash's Timer class
    private var oneSecTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);

    public var timerHasStopped:Boolean = false;

    public function MainTimer() {
        // constructor code
        trace("Main timer is here");
        currentMin = 2;
        currentSec = 5;

        minBox.text = String(currentMin);
        if(currentSec < 10){
            secBox.text = "0" + String(currentSec); //concatenate with a leading zero
           }else{
               secBox.text = String(currentSec);
           }//if end
           oneSecTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
           oneSecTimer.start();

    } // ends onTimerComplete

} //public function maintimer end
        private function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void{

        currentSec = currentSec - 1;

        if (currentSec < 0){
            currentSec = 59;
            currentMin -= 1;
        } //end if
        if (currentMin < 0){
            currentMin = 0;
            currentSec = 0;
            timerHasStopped = true;
        }else{
            oneSecTimer.start();
        } //end else

        //update our display
        minBox.text = String(currentMin);
        secBox.text = String(currentSec);
        //Adjust display for seconds less than 10
        if (currentSec < 10){
                secBox.text = "0" + String(currentSec);
        } // end if
    }// end onTimerComplete
```

} //public end
} //package end

Answer (score 0):

From what i can tell you have a `}` to much. Delete the one with the comment

`}//public function maintimer end`